# How to change the fundamental underlying container type for the adaptor containers?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I want to use stack, which uses list as a fundamental container and not vector. How can I do so? As I know by default the stack will use vector. How can I ensure that the stack will use only the container I have mentioned. For example, I want stack to use - list only.

Comment: Stacks actually use deques by default, so you won't get the painful full copies when inserting.

Comment: `std::queue` also uses deque by default. `std::priority_queue` is implemented as a heap structure, so it uses a vector on its back end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the required container as templatized parameter. For example:

```
std::stack<int,std::vector<int> > stack_using_vector_of_int;
std::stack<std::string,std::list<std::string> > stack_using_list_of_string;
```

If you want to make sure `stack` always uses list, give a type definition of `list_stack` that always uses `std::list` as container.

Adding from Jarod42's comment:

> Post C++11 you can use
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> using list_stack = std::stack<T, std::list<T>>;
> ```

By default `std::stack` uses `std::deque` as underlying container which is almost always more efficient than using `std::list` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, looks like there is no iterator for the adaptor containers.

Comment: @user3629119 They are *container adaptors*. So they are not containers.

Comment: Definition of `list_stack` in C++11 : `template <typename T> using list_stack = std::stack<T, std::list<T>>;`